# Walking to infinity stepping on randomly selected lattice points

Tags: probability, random-walk, integer-lattices

Suppose you randomly fill the infinite non-negative quadrant of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $1$'s and $0$'s, with $1$ occurring with probability $p$ (and $0$ with probability $1-p$).
The lowerleft corner of the quadrant is at the origin $(0,0)$, marked red below:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \color{red}{1} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

> What is the probability that you can walk to $\infty$ starting
>   at the origin, stepping only on $1$'s, moving one step N, S, E, or W at a time?

It cannot be $1$ regardless of the value of $p$, because there is always a $(1-p)$ chance that the origin itself is assigned $0$ and your walk cannot begin.
In the example above (which I generated with $p=0.7$), you can walk to the
boundary of the $5 \times 5$ snippet shown. But already with $50 \times 50$
and $p=0.7$, rarely can the boundary be reached.

Is the answer zero independent of how close $p$ is to $1$?
That would be somewhat counterintuitive...

Comment: On the whole square lattice Z^2, the threshold for *bond percolation* is known to be around 0.5927, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold.

Comment: @Did: Yes, thanks, I know that threshold. It does not seem to yield the answer to my question. Nor would it (I think) if I filled all of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @Did: I think you mean *site percolation*? (Also see [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PercolationThreshold.html).)

Comment: @joriki Yes, *site*. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke This shows there is a threshold, that is, that the probability that one can walk to infinity is zero for every $p<p^*$ and positive for every $p>p^*$, for some $p^*$ in $(0,1)$. And, as is frequent in this context, the exact value of $p^*$ should be extremely difficult to determine. Aren't these your two questions?

Comment: Does "walking to infinity" mean that the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the path both $\rightarrow\infty$, or just that they are unbounded?

Comment: @Did: My understanding is that beyond the site percolation threshold, there is some infinite component, not necessarily some infinite component containing the origin.

Comment: @stewbasic: I meant: The path does not stay inside any fixed-radius circle centered on the origin.

Comment: If you want an introductory reference to (bond) percolation and its relations to statistical physics, you can find one here: http://www.unige.ch/~duminil/publi/Courspeccot2.pdf

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke It is known and quite general that there is an infinite cluster with positive probability if and only if there is an infinite cluster containing the origin with positive probability.

Comment: My hunch is that  $p^∗ \in (0.7,0.8)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no path to infinity, then there is a contiguous wall of zeros connecting the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis, with diagonal adjacency allowed. The probability of such a wall existing is bounded from above by the sum of the existence probabilities of all possible walls. Any wall starts at some point $n\ge0$ on the $x$-axis and traverses at least $n+1$ zeros before reaching the $y$-axis. In each of the at least $n$ steps, it has $5$ directional options, since if it retraces itself or moves diagonally backwards we could streamline it, and the initial step also has at most $5$ directions to go. So the sum of all existence probabilities is at most

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty5^kq^{k+1}=\frac1{1-5q}\sum_{n=0}^\infty5^nq^{n+1}=\frac{q}{(1-5q)^2}\;,
$$

where $q=1-p$. Equating this to $1$ yields $q=(11-\sqrt{21})\,/\,50\approx0.12835$. But we can do better than that: For any given $m$, there is a finite probability for the path to traverse all walls up to $m$ steps, and thus a finite probability to reach infinity unless there is a wall with at least $m$ steps. Thus we can consider

$$
\sum_{n=m}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty5^kq^{k+1}=\frac1{1-5q}\sum_{n=m}^\infty5^nq^{n+1}=\frac{q(5q)^m}{(1-5q)^2}\;.
$$

This is less than $1$ for sufficiently large $m$ if $q\lt0.2$. Thus $p^*\le0.8$, as you guessed.

We can do yet better by taking into account that after an axis-parallel step there are only $3$ different directions for the wall to take without allowing us to streamline it. Denoting by $a_j$ and $b_j$ the number of walls with $j$ steps that end and don't end in an axis-parallel step, respectively, we have

$$
\pmatrix{a\\b}_{j+1}=\pmatrix{1&2\\2&3}\pmatrix{a\\b}_j\;.
$$

The greater eigenvalue of this matrix is $2+\sqrt5\approx4.236$, so we should have

$$p^*\le1-\frac1{2+\sqrt5}=3-\sqrt5\approx0.764\;.$$

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/43a9e3ca13a500a6570a0409e61924ba) that estimates the expected Manhattan distance $d$ reachable from the origin. Here's a log-log plot of the results for $0.5\le p\le0.591$:

[image: log-log plot of the expected Manhattan distance reachable from the origin]

The $x$-axis shows $-\log(\tilde p_{\mathbb Z^2}-p)$, where $\tilde p_{\mathbb Z^2}=0.5927460507921$ is the best known estimate of the site percolation threshold for the square lattice, and the $y$-axis shows $\log\langle d\rangle$. The roughly linear relationship suggests $p^*=p^*_{\mathbb Z^2}$.

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/258f4e368557149f95619ac8765308f6) that estimates the probability to reach $x=50$ or $y=50$; here's the result:

[image: probability to reach x=50 or y=50]

The red data points show the results of the simulation; the green curve is the crude approximation

$$
p\cdot\frac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}\;,
$$

where the factor $p$ is for the origin itself to be a $1$ and the other factor is the probability that a single $1$ leads to two $1$s before it leads to two $0$s.

The results are clearly compatible with $p^*=p^*_{\mathbb Z^2}$. At $p=0.7$, the boundary is reached roughly half the time. As you say it can rarely be reached, there might be a bug in your code.

Comment: There is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance the origin is $0$, and a $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{4}$ chance the origin is $1$ but the two adjacent points are $0$. So that already places $p^* > 0.625$.

Comment: Beautiful analysis, and $0.76$ is consistent with what I have observed. Thanks!